# Heroku Failed to detect set buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, rubygems

Hello I'm a noob on Heroku, ving trouble pushing my rails app.

Afterentering:
$ git push heroku master

I get the following error from the terminal:

Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

So I researched this error and followed the steps here:
devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

and set the buildpack by entering into the terminal:
 $heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby

Comment: From that same link: "Heroku’s Ruby buildpack expects a `Gemfile` to be present in the root folder of an application to correctly identify its type, but if the buildpack of an application is set to `heroku/ruby` and no `Gemfile` is present, the application will fail to build." Do you have a `Gemfile` in the root of your repository? (You shouldn't normally have to manually set your buildpack.)